# Why NSJSONSerialization uses NSData instead of NSString?

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsjsonserialization

Is there any reason for `NSJSONSerialization` to use `NSData` instead of `NSString` for representing JSON data?

`NSString` seems like a more obvious choice to me...

Comment: Most methods that retrieve data from `NSURLConnection` return a `NSData` (in order to be agnostic about the sort of data being retrieved), so it's logical that a method to convert that to a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` would take a `NSData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine it would be more efficient to encourage parsing `NSData` instead of `NSString`. If you are parsing a response from a server, for example, you'll get an `NSData` object representing a buffer of raw bytes returned from the server (note that `NSJSONSerialization` also includes a method for parsing an `NSInputStream` directly). Parsing the whole thing into an `NSString` would be a waste since that would just be an intermediate object that would get thrown out. Instead, `NSJSONSerialization` is probably parsing the bytes in the `NSData` object directly and only construct `NSStrings` for the appropriate keys and values in the resulting data structure.